# How to efficiently turn a boolean numpy array into threshold boolean array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, vectorization

I'm using **Python 2.7** and **NumPy** to work on big arrays of boolean values.

I have an array A, that is something like this:

```
>>> A
array([[[False, False, True, True, True],
        [False, False, False, True, True],
        [False, False, True, True, True],
        [False, False, False, True, True],
        [False, False, False, False, True]],

       [[False, True, True, True, True],
        [False, True, True, True, True],
        [False, False, True, True, True],
        [False, True, True, True, True],
        [False, False, True, True, True]]])
```

I have to turn it in a boolean array like this:

```
>>> B
array([[[True, False, True, True, True],
        [True, True, False, True, True],
        [True, False, True, True, True],
        [True, True, False, True, True],
        [True, True, True, False, True]],

       [[False, True, True, True, True],
        [False, True, True, True, True],
        [True, False, True, True, True],
        [False, True, True, True, True],
        [True, False, True, True, True]]])
```

So the idea is that the last `False` value of each row should remain and any other value should become `True`.
I need to create it in order to use it as a mask for another array.

Is there a way to do it with **NumPy** without using `for` loops (that are quite slow)?

Comment: This is an odd transformation - you're basically losing all information other than the index of the last False value. What's the point of this?

Comment: @Marcin As I wrote in the question, I need to use the resulting array as a mask for another numpy array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use the xor operator `^` for that purpose. Simply "leftshift" the array by one and add `True` values to the right and then xor the new and the old array:

```
A = np.array([[False, False, True, True, True],
              [False, False, False, True, True],
              [False, False, True, True, True],
              [False, False, False, True, True],
              [False, False, False, False, True]])

X = np.hstack((A[:,1:], 
               np.array(np.ones((A.shape[0], 1)), dtype=np.bool))))
>>> array([[False, True, True, True, True],
           [False, False, True, True, True],
           [False, True, True, True, True],
           [False, False, True, True, True],
           [False, False, False, True, True]])

np.invert(A ^ X)
>>> array([[True, False, True, True, True],
           [True, True, False, True, True],
           [True, False, True, True, True],
           [True, True, False, True, True],
           [True, True, True, False, True]])
```

This only works if all `False` values are left and followed by only `True` values.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is the fastest!

Comment: This looks like a promising idea - can it be made to work with the full array `A` given in the question (rather than just the simpler array)?

Comment: @ajcr I did it by adding a dimension to each matrix and replacing `hstack` with `concatenate`.

Comment: @ProGM Thanks for explaining - I like this method a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way that works for your array (and also works for arrays with more mixed up rows such as `[F, T, T, F, T]` too):

```
>>> x = 4 - np.argmin(A[:,:,::-1], axis=2)[:,:,np.newaxis]
>>> (np.arange(5) * np.ones_like(A)) != x
array([[[ True, False,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True, False,  True,  True],
        [ True, False,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True, False,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True, False,  True]],

       [[False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False,  True,  True,  True],
        [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False,  True,  True,  True]]], dtype=bool)
```

Explanation:

- Flip the array `A` on `axis=2` and use `argmin` across that axis to get the index of the first `False` value.
- We need to know the index of the last occurrence of `False` in `A` (not the first occurrence in the flipped array). This is the value of the depth of the array (i.e. 5), minus 1, minus the index found in the previous step.
- Make this new array of indices compatible with `A` by adding a new axis (`axis=2`). Call this new array of indices `x`.
- Construct an array of the same dimensions as `A` where each row of `axis=2` is `np.arange(5)`. The desired boolean array is found by testing for inequality of this constructed array with `x`.

Comment: +1 for the idea, but hildensia version is faster. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you invert the array, you can use [`numpy.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero) to find all the (originally) false entries, then take the last one in each row from that. You can then use that to construct your mask array.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple problem. You need to select each row. Find the positions of **False** using **np.where()** and place **True** in those positions except the last one denoted by **index [-1]**. This is done in the code given below:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A=np.array([[[False, False, True, True, True],
         [False, False, False, True, True],
         [False, False, True, True, True],
         [False, False, False, True, True],
         [False, False, False, False, True]],

        [[False, True, True, True, True],
         [False, True, True, True, True],
         [False, False, True, True, True],
         [False, True, True, True, True],
         [False, False, True, True, True]]])

>>> for mat in A:
     opmat=[]
     for arr in mat:
         index=np.where(arr==False)
         arr[index[0][:-1]]=True
         opmat.append(arr)
     out.append(opmat)

>>> out=np.array(out)
>>> out
array([[[ True, False,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True, False,  True,  True],
        [ True, False,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True, False,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True, False,  True]],

       [[False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False,  True,  True,  True],
        [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False,  True,  True,  True]]], dtype=bool)
```